# Process entire files in Hadoop using Python code (preferably in Dumbo)

Tags: python, hadoop, apache-pig

It seems a very common use case but so hard to do in Hadoop (it is possible with WholeFileRecordReader class).
Is it at all possible in Dumbo or Pig?
Does anyone knows a way to process whole files as map tasks using Dumbo or Pig?

Comment: Thank you for answers. Reading about file splitting in Hadoop, I see that the standard split size is 64 MB. My files are small (few hundred KB) and packed into a HAR. Does it mean that they won't get split and are actually processed one per map task? Or even several per map task (because of HAR)?

Comment: No, har will not decrease the number of maps. You need to use MultiFileInputSplit. If you use Pig, Pig automatically combines small files starting from 0.8 (http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.9.0/perf.html#combine-files).

Answer (score 0):

WholeFileRecordReader means not split the input file? If so, define mapred.min.split.size to a very large value, both mapreduce and Pig will take it.

Comment: Thank you. That sounds very simple but on which node do I need to set it (I'm using remote Hadoop cluster)?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you want to have one file as on record in Pig. If not, please be more specific in your question.

I don't know of a Pig storage loader that loads the entire file at once (in either the standard distribution or in piggybank). I suggest you write your own [Pig custom loader](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.7.0/udf.html#Load+Functions), which is relatively easy.